# Load a UItableView and its data on back button click in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xcode4

I have a `UITableView` in which I m loading `NSMutableArray` data .The data is from service url.Now when I elect a particular I am directing it other view which contains data in detail.I have a navigationbar in `SecondViewController` and a back button on it.If I click the button it should reload the prevoius tableviews data which it has already loaded.
But now when Im doing it back button is working and going back to prevoius view but I couldnot see the `UITableView` and data in it ..I dont know where I m going wrong...

This is the code..

```
-(IBAction)switchtofirst
{
FirstViewController *gp=[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
 [gp.tableView reloadData];
[self presentModalViewController:gp animated:NO];
[gp release];

}
```

What else I have to do to get back UITableView and its data back  in UITableView ?

Any help would be appreciated...

Thanks ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to create object and write code like that.

in Back Btn Action You just write

```
-(IBAction)switchtofirst
   {

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

   }
```

Try this

I hope it will works fine

Answer (score 0):

On button click just use the following code.

```
 -(IBAction)switchtofirst
    {
     [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```